# Show active arrow onclick (Vertical Navigation ?)

Tags: javascript, css, navigation

On [this page](http://chesapeakepro.missionmedia.net/about) on the right side I have a collapsing/expanding nav that when clicked (i.e. "What We Do," shows three more nav items) shows more nav items.

Under/behind each nav item you can somewhat see a blue arrow.  The design should look as seen [here](http://chesapeakepro.missionmedia.net/images/rightNAV-active-inactive-how.jpg).

How do I code it so the blue active and inactive arrows show to the left of each nav item (word) as seen in the photo I linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your styles, add

```
padding-left: 18px;
```

to your selector

```
#rightside-interior li a
```

and it will move the text over but not the background image.

Comment: great thank you!  THe inactive arrow is working.  Yet how do I show the  active (down arrow) arrow when one of the main nav items is clicked ("What We Do," "Who We Are")?

Comment: Without looking too deep into your javascript, there are a couple things I see wrong. Install firebug in firefox and hit your site: there are multiple javascript errors that may be causing things to fail. Also, the "active" arrow appears when you click down on the mouse, but changes back when you release the mouse button. Don't use onmousedown and onmouseup to make the arrows active, use onclick.